# Google's Bayesian Structural Time-Series

Tags: time-series, causalimpact

I am attempting to get my head around Google's Causal Impact paper, which isn't completely clear to me.

In the methodology part of the paper, the authors say: **"The framework of our model allows us to choose from among a large set of potential controls by placing a spike-and-slab prior on the set of regression coefficients and by allowing the model to average over the set of controls "**. My question is the following: For the synthetic control variables, I know that we're supposed to come up with the variables that are determining y, but do not receive the treatment, but I am unclear whether Causal Impact runs an automatic test to examine whether those variables are actually useful as controls.

Their Github post: https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html

Paper: https://research.google/pubs/pub41854/

Not sure that's the right community for the post, but I could not find anything related to questions about DS papers

Comment: It is my understanding (from a quick read) that the selection of counter-factual variables is automatic and also adapt themselves via Bayesian updating rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide an answer after a quick read of the sources.

Selection of predictors for counter-factual outcomes (the outcome if the policy was not effective), is done automaticaly via [Bayesian Spike and Slab method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike-and-slab_regression) which is designed for automatic selection in mind.

Both the [original paper](https://research.google/pubs/pub41854/) and [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_structural_time_series#General_model_description) state so (emphasis mine):

> The model consists of three main components:
>
> 1. Kalman filter. The technique for time series decomposition. In this step, a researcher can add different state variables: trend,
>    seasonality, regression, and others.
> 2. Spike-and-slab method. **In this step, the most important regression predictors are selected**.
> 3. Bayesian model averaging. Combining the results and prediction calculation.